# Safe way to derive IV from the DH shared keys for AES-GCM?

Tags: aes, diffie-hellman, tls, gcm, aes-gcm

I am preparing to use AES-GCM to make a secure communication program. 
Here is the procedure

1. DH key exchange to get shared keys
2. SHA256(shared keys)
3. Use AES-GCM to encrypt a message while the key only used once.

However, I was confused about the way to get IV in step3. I know IV/nonuse must be unique. The size of the IV should be 96 bits. I know we can use the timestamp to generate iv. However, I need to generate the IV from the shared key. Is there any method to do it safely?

Comment: Why do you need to generate the nonce from the shared key? The usual practice is using LFSR/Counter as recommended by NIST, or you can combine both as in [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/77986/18298). In step 2, better use a KDF, like HKDF.

Comment: Hi kelalaka. Thanks for your comment! That requirement is from my supervisor. After doing some research, i'm little confused about the implementation of HKDF. I think the right way to implement it is to do one extract and several expands. However, the package in pycryoptodome combine the extract and expand process together. Therefore, there is no way to do one extract and several expands in this package. Am i misunderstanding the HKDF?

Comment: As far as I remember, pycryoptodome does that. It is open-source, you can build one for your cause.

Comment: You mean the key generated from the HKDF? Just once

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no regulatory requirement, for AES-128, a good option would be splitting the SHA-256 hash into a key (128-bit), IV (96-bit), and any unused portion. That allows us to make the IV implicit (and secret, which is unnecessary, but does not harm) thus saves even so little bandwidth. For AES-192 or AES-256,  we can do this with SHA-512 instead of using SHA-256.

On a related note, make sure that the same derived key is never used by a given party both to encrypt and decrypt/authenticate because that opens to mirror attacks. If the communication is bidirectional, derivation could use 
$$\operatorname{HMAC-SHA-xyz}(\mathsf{key}=\text{DH-shared-secret}, \mathsf{message}=\text{sender-ID})$$
as the origin of the session key and IV used by the sender to prepare its message. HMAC internally hashes the shared secret if it more than a certain size (64 bytes for SHA-256), that's fine.

For even stronger assurance:
$$\begin{align}
\text{Key}&=\operatorname{HMAC-SHA-xyz}(\mathsf{key}=\text{DH-shared-secret}, \mathsf{message}=\text{'K'}\mathbin\|\text{sender-ID})\\
\text{IV}&=\operatorname{HMAC-SHA-xyz}(\mathsf{key}=\text{DH-shared-secret}, \mathsf{message}=\text{'I'}\mathbin\|\text{sender-ID})
\end{align}$$

which gives an argument that the leak of IV (which should be assumed even if the IV is not sent in clear) can't harm the secrecy of Key even if the hash has some level of defect. Also, HMAC has a parameter (now shown) to specify the output size, making the definition cleaner.

Comment: There is one problem here; if they plan to use the derived AES key more than once, then the IV will be the same. To mitigate, add a counter to HMAC, that can be transferred, too.

Comment: Hi, fgrieu. Thanks for your answer! I am a newbie in cryptography. I am a little confused about your answer. Did you mean i should compute HMAC-SHA to get key and iv, and then put key and iv into AES-GCM? From what i learned, HMAC is used for message authentication with models like AES-CBC.

Comment: @FRANKfisher HMAC is a PRF, that is why we can use it. Another Choice is [HKDF](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/76589/18298)

Comment: @kelalaka Got it. Thank you so much!