# salsa20 (Key, Nonce) repeatable?

Tags: nonce, salsa20

in Salsa20, the Key is 128 or 256 bits, the Nonce is 64 bits. the pair (k,r) should never be reused. Does it means, if the key is fixed, the encryption can only run 2^64 times? if the key is not fixed, after running 2^192 or 2^320 times, the pair must be used repeatedly. If I use the this stream cipher in a busy network, does it means it is vulnerable due to the two-times pad?

Comment: Does this answer satisfy you? [How to generate a nonce for ChaCha20 Poly1305?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/77982/18298)

Comment: "if the key is not fixed, after running 2^192 or 2^320 times..." - we will, in the lifetime of the universe, use Salsa20 $2^{192}$ times, much less $2^{320}$